# Why doesn't MyData[,x] behave the same way as MyData$Columnx when MyData$Columnx == MyData[,x] in R?

Tags: r

I was typing `MyData$Column1`, `MyData$Column2`, etc. too many times, so I wanted to create a function f which made that shorter.

I tried

```
f1 <- function(x){
return((MyData$x))
}
```

but f1(Column1) always returned NULL, and so would f1("Column2").

However, when I defined

```
f2 <- function(y){
return(MyData[,y]
}
```

This worked, that is, f2(2) returns column 2.

What really mystifies me is that if I run

```
MyData[,2] == MyData$Column2
```

then I get the same answer.

I've looked into how different environments are defined in R (i.e., the global environment is different from the environment inside a specific function, and you'd need to use the <<- if you wanted to write over a global variable inside a function environment, etc.).

But that doesn't seem to be related to this problem: If I can access MyData in one case, I should also be able to do so in the other.

I've also generally searched Google and StackOverflow, and looked over the documentation for $.

Comment: I don't understand, df$x1 will return the same as df[,1], you must have made a mistake.

Comment: In f1 - you can't use the `$` to extract a variable like that. You need to use `[[` - so `MyData[[x]]`would work for you. See [this for explanation of extract operators](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md)

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem. please add the dataset, and proper code

Comment: You are more likely to get a meaningful answer if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451).